# sqlite database (code 14) error

Tags: android, sqlite

could anyone please help me :(

i want to make book and use these codes:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private database db; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        db = new database(this); 
        db.useable();

    }

}
```

and for database class:

```
public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    public final String   path = "data/data/com.example.book/databases/"; 
    public final String   Name = "database";                             
    public SQLiteDatabase mydb;                                          

    private final Context mycontext;


    public database(Context context) { 

        super(context, "database", null, 1);
        mycontext = context;

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void useable() {

        boolean checkdb = checkdb();

        if (checkdb) {

        } else {

            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copydatabase();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {}

        }

    }


    public void open() {

        mydb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + Name, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }


    @Override
    public void close() {
        mydb.close();
    }


    public boolean checkdb() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + Name, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {

        }
        mydb.close();
        return db != null ? true : false;

    }


    public void copydatabase() throws IOException {

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(path + Name);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        InputStream myInput = mycontext.getAssets().open(Name);
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myInput.close();
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
    }
```

but i got force close and these errors

```
E/SQLiteDatabase(1567): Failed to open database 'data/data/com.example.book/databases/database'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

my database file is in assets folder with "database" name , my emulator is genymotion

Comment: Is your package name **com.example.book**? In error it display like **com.example.book1**.

Comment: sorry , i test on 2 different code and the logs are changed . package name is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
replace

```
public final String   path = "data/data/com.example.book/databases/";
```

with

```
String yourPath = myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().replace("files",
"databases")+File.separator + DB_NAME;
```